# Using Machine Translation in WorldServer10.3.0

Tags: worldserver

I want to use machine translation in WorldServer recently.
I know this can be realized by uploading an adapter to WorldServer and configuring it for use.
But I don't know where can I find these adapters.
Could anyone know ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is primarily a Stack Exchange site for SDL Web / SDL Tridion. You may not get the answer you're looking on here. Perhaps try contacting WorldServer support? Searching in the online docs of v10.4.4 (earliest version on docs.sdl.com) gives this topic, "Configuring Machine Translation Adapters" http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20WorldServer-v1/GUID-1ECC3FED-FCFD-43AA-A160-0CD71405E790

Comment: I posted this on [SDL Community](https://community.sdl.com/developers/language-developers/f/283/t/9170), asking if it'd be a good question on our WorldServer forum or where else Heimei could ask.

Comment: See the [response on SDL Community](https://community.sdl.com/developers/language-developers/f/283/p/9170/35275?Redirected=true). In addition to David's link, community member Claudia shared more about [machine translation adapters](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20WorldServer-v1/GUID-165C9C64-68DC-43B6-B57F-D19C20117FD9).